# How to get Emacs key bindings to recognize capital letters?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I get Emacs to recognize M-C (meta-shift-c) rather than translating it as m-c?

Currently when I do `C-h k M-C` I get:
`M-c (translated from M-C) runs the command capitalize-word.`

How do I get it to NOT translate M-C to M-c?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use modifier `S` (Shift) in your key binding. E.g.:

```
(global-set-key "\M-\S-c" 'foobar)
```

If there is nothing explicitly bound to the shifted key then Emacs automatically translates it to the unshifted key.

From the Elisp manual, node `Key Sequence Input`:

> > If an input character is upper-case (or has the shift modifier) and has no key binding, but its lower-case equivalent has one, then `read-key-sequence' converts the character to lower case.  Note that`lookup-key' does not perform case conversion in this way.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was confused because Aquamacs automatically distinguishes between `m-c` and `M-C` and picks up the latter as `m-s-c`. I see now that for GNU Emacs, you have to specify the shift modifier separately.

Comment: Wait, actually it doesn't work. I tried `(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-S-c") 'enable-auto-capitalize-mode)` and `(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "\M-\S-c") 'enable-auto-capitalize-mode)`.

Comment: If you use `kbd` then do not use `\M` etc syntax: `kbd` expects the same syntax you see in output, when you use `C-h k`. But it seems that you have to use either string or vector syntax, not `kbd`, for this. So try `(define-key mymap "\M-\S-c" 'mycmd)` or `(define-key mymap [(meta shift ?c)] 'mycmd)`. Or `(define-key mymap (kbd "M-C") 'mycmd)`.

Comment: FYI - You unaccepted this answer in favor of Stefan's, 9 months later. 
That is the same answer. (He writes `M-C`, but that is the same as `M-S-c`.)

Comment: Seems like that way is simpler, no?

Comment: @PeterSalazar: What is simpler? That "simpler way" is the exact **same answer**,  except that Stefan gives no details about it - he does not show how to "*add a binding for `M-C`*". I said the same thing: the answer is to add such a binding, and I showed what that means (how to do it), and I pointed to the Emacs doc that explains what's going on and why the OP's attempt at a solution failed. What am I missing about the "simpler way" you see?

Answer (score 4):

To get Emacs to distinguish the two is very easy: add a binding for `M-C`.  The translation from `M-C` to `M-c` happens as a fallback when no binding was found for `M-C`.